# Updating Sharepoint 2013 Property Bag Settings using Code

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Is there any PowerShell command/script or any other methods to access and update the SharePoint 2013 property bag settings? I don't want to update via Sharepoint 2013 Central Administration Portal.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below code to update property bag:

```
$web=get-spweb http://sp13
$web.AllProperties["Key"] = "New Value"
$web.Update()
```

---

Update:

For farm propety bag, you could update a farm property like this:

```
$farm=Get-SPFarm
$farm.Properties["name"] = "value"
$farm.Update()
```

Comment: We have all the properties made at farm level. Is there anyway to access to the same ?